# regex to match question sentences in long text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long text in form of a string.

This text includes a lot of questions that are at the same time the headers of sections.

These headers always start with a number+dot+whitespace character combination and end with a question mark, I am trying to extract these strings.

This is what I've got so far: `longString.match(/\d\.\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s\\?/g)`.
Sure enough this doesn't work.

Comment: Try `^\d\.\s+\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*\?$` https://regex101.com/r/45XPQv/1

Comment: Or, `longString.match(/\d+\.\s+[^?]*\?/g)`, or `longString.match(/^\d+\.\s[^]*?\?/gm)`

Answer (score 2):

In your example you use `[a-zA-Z]+`, but you might extend that to matching 1 or more word characters using `\w+`

This part at the end of the pattern `\s\\?` matches an expected whitespace char followed by an optional backslash.

---

To match multiple words, you can optionally repeat the pattern to match a word preceded by 1 or more whitespace characters.

You one option is to use

```
\d\.\s+\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*\?
```

**Explanation**

- `\d\.` Match a single digit (for 1 or digits use `\d+`)
- `\s+\w+` Match a `.` and 1+ whitspace chars and 1+ word chars
- `(?:\s+\w+)*` Optionally repeat 1+ whitspace chars and 1+ word chars
- `\s*\?` Match 0+ whitespace chars and a question mark.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/38CBmJ/1)

A broader match might be matching at least a single time any char except a question mark or whitespace char after the digit, dot and whitespace:

```
\d\.\s+[^\s?]+(?:\s+[^\s?]+)*\?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K1n7rS/1)